# Accessing the type of clicked element in Angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

In Angular is there a way to access the type of element that was clicked? I have the following in jQuery and it works fine, the trouble is I don't know how to do the equivalent in an Angular project I've been asked to look at.

```
// Click action
$(".contactlist").on("click", function(e) {

    if (!$(e.target).is(':checkbox') && !$(e.target).is("li:nth-child(1)")) {
        var token = $(this).data('token');
        window.location.href = "XYZ.php?page=contacts&token=" + token;
    }

});
```

How can I modify this Angular event handler to work like the above jQuery?

```
$scope.eventHandler = function(data) {
        window.location.href = "XYZ.php?page=contacts&token=" + data.token;
};
```

Something like this????

```
$scope.eventHandler = function(data) {
    if (!$(this.target).is(':checkbox') && !$(this.target).is("li:nth-child(1)")) {
        window.location.href = "XYZ.php?page=contacts&token=" + data.token;
    }
};
```

The HTML

```
<li><input type="checkbox" class="check" data-token="{{data.token}}" name="addselect[]"></li>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery? `$(this.target)` is jQuery, not Angular.

Comment: Yes jQuery library is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a directive with element.bind.

```
  app.directive('clickMe', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attr, html) {
    element.bind('mouseup', function() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(attr));
      });
    };
  });
```

Your HTML would be like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-token="{{data.token}}" click-me name="addselect[]">
```

Returns the following for a checkbox:

```
{"$attr":{"type":"type","class":"class","token":"data-token","clickMe":"click-me","name":"name"},"$$element":{"0":{"ng339":7},"length":1},"type":"checkbox","class":"check","token":"","clickMe":"","name":"addselect[]","$$observers":{"token":[]}}
```

In the directive, if you JUST want to get the type, attr.type will provide it.

```
checkbox
```